# Prove: $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x }{x-1} d x=\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I'd like your help with proving that
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x }{x-1}d x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}.$$
I tried to use Fourier series, or to use a power series and integrate it twice but it didn't work out for me.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: *Hint*: take the derivative of $\ln{x}\ln(1-x)$, and remember that $x\ln{x}\rightarrow{0}$ as $x\rightarrow{0}$.

Comment: Fiddling with this led me to think about $\lim\limits_{x\to0+}((\log x)(\log(1-x)))$. Maybe if I ever have a class of bright students taking calculus, I'll assign this.  (...and I see "bgins" also thought of that.)

Comment: @bgins: Can you please extend your comment? I'm not sure I understand what to do.

Comment: @Jozef: $[\ln(x)\ln(1-x)]'=\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}+\frac{\ln{x}}{x-1}$. Integrating, the LHS is zero because of the limit mentioned. Then, we have the same situation as americo-tavares and peter below, except their routes are better because more they are direct (no pulling rabbits out of hats)!

Comment: I think it's appropriate to mention that, if one wishes to use the power series representation of $f(x)={\ln(1-x)\over x}$ on $(-1,1)$, the following theorem (which is not usually mentioned in an introductory Calculus sequence) is needed: 
Suppose a power series $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$  converges on $[a,b)$ and suppose $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n  {b^{n+1}\over n+1}$ converges. Then  $f(x)$ is improperly integrable on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx= \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n\int_a^b x^n\, dx$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: If we prove that the original integral is convergent, do we still need applying this theorem?

Comment: @AméricoTavares I'm not sure (I shouldn't have said "needed")... The fact in my previous comment was the only theorem I could find that justifies the method. I'd be interested to know the answer to your question too.

Comment: @AméricoTavares You could apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence, no?

Comment: @DavidMitra You may be right, but honestly I really don't know.

Comment: You're missing a $\textrm{d}x$ in your integral.

Comment: [Inverse question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100495): how to compute $\int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{\ln x} d x$?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hint: use the substitution $u=1-x$ to obtain
$$
I:=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{x-1}dx=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln \left( 1-u\right) 
}{u}\,du
$$

and [the following Maclaurin series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions)
$$
\ln \left( 1-u\right) =-u-\frac{1}{2}u^{2}-\frac{1}{3}u^{3}-\ldots -\frac{
u^{n+1}}{n+1}-\ldots\qquad(\left\vert u\right\vert <1) 
$$

Comment: In case anybody reads this answer, I think it is necessary to say something like for all $u\in(0,1)$ and for all $n\in\Bbb N$, $$\left|1+\frac12u+\frac13u^2+\cdots\frac1nu^{n-1}\right|\leq-\frac{\ln(1-u)}u=g(u)$$ so that, since $g$ is integrable on $(0,1)$, one can apply dominated convergence, and swap the sum with the integral.

Comment: @Olivier Bégassat Thanks for your comment. I've just assumed, without justification, that the given integral could be evaluated by expanding the integrand in a series and integrating term by term.

Answer (score 12):

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\log x}{x-1}dx =\lambda$$

Making $x = 1-u$ produces (keep the $x$)

$$-\int_0^1 \frac{\log (1-x)}{x}dx=\lambda$$

$$\frac{\log (1-x)}{x}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{n}$$

$$-\int_0^1 \frac{\log (1-x)}{x}dx =\left.\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n^2} \right|_0^1 =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Comment: This is exactly Américo's answer (in fact all alnswers are the same :-) )

Answer (score 11):

Write $\ln x = \ln(1 + (x-1))$ and use the log series

Answer (score 10):

Related problem: [I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215343/int-01-frac-ln-1-xx-without-power-series/215365#215365), [II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385862/evaluating-int-0-infty-big-fracxa-1-sinh-x-xa-2-big-dx/385918#385918). Using the change of variables $u=-\ln(x)$ and the identity

> $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{s-1}}{e^u -1}=\zeta{(s)}\Gamma{(s)} $$

we reach to the deisred result

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x }{x-1}= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u}{e^u -1}=\zeta{(2)}\Gamma{(2)} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}. $$

**Added:** Note that,

> $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{s-1}}{e^u - 1}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{s-1}}{e^u}(1-e^{-u})^{-1}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}{u^{s-1}e^{-(n+1)u}}$$
>
> $$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^s} \int_{0}^{\infty}{y^{s-1}e^{-y}}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s} \Gamma(s)= \zeta(s) \Gamma(s).$$

Comment: Where does the result for this last integral come from?

Comment: @Alex: See the added.

Answer (score 5):

*Hint:* Use a geometric sum and a partial integration  $$\int_0^1x^n\log x \,dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\log x \bigg|_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{x^{n}}{n+1}$$

---

**Edit:** The first step is 
$$\frac{\log x}{x-1}=-\frac{\log x}{1-x}=-\log x\sum_{k=0}x^k$$

---

Answer (score 0):

Using the expansion series $\displaystyle\frac 1{1-x}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n,\, |x|<1$, we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int_0^1\frac{x^a}{x-1}\, dx&=& -\int_0^1 x^a\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n}\, dx\right)\\
  &=& -\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\int_0^1 x^{n+a}\, dx\right)\\
  &=& -\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{(n+a+1)}\\
  &=& -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{(n+a)}
  \end{eqnarray*}
Differentiate wrt $a$, we obtain
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int_0^1\frac{x^a\ln(x)}{x-1}\, dx  &=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{(n+a)^2}
  \end{eqnarray*}
Fix $a=0$ in both sides, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{x-1}\, dx  &=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2}\\
  &=&\frac{\pi^2}6.
  \end{eqnarray*}