# $\int_0^1 {\frac{{\ln (1 - x)}}{x}}$ without power series

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there a way to calculate $$\int_0^1{ \ln (1 - x)\over x}\;dx$$ without using power series?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108248/prove-int-01-frac-ln-x-x-1-sum-1-infty-frac1n2/279065#279065). Using the change of variables $x=1-e^{-t}$ and taking advatage of the fact that

$$\Gamma(s)\zeta(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-1}}{e^{t}-1}\,, $$

the value of the integral follows

$$ -\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t}{e^{t}-1} \,dt = -\zeta(2) = -\frac{\pi^2}{6}   \,.$$

Comment: You can get the indefinite integral in terms of the dilogarithm function.

Answer (score 10):

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 {\frac{{\ln (1 - x)}}{x}}dx\\
=& \ \frac43 \bigg( \int_0^1 {\frac{{\ln (1 - x)}}{x}}
\overset{x\to \frac{1-x}{1+x}} {dx}  - \frac14\int_0^1 {\frac{{\ln (1 - x)}}{x}}
\overset{x\to (\frac{1-x}{1+x} )^2} {dx}\bigg)\\
=& \ \frac43 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}dx
=\frac43 \int_0^1 \int_0^\infty \frac{-y}{(1+y^2)(1+x^2y^2)}dy\ dx \\
=& -\frac43\int_0^\infty\frac{\tan^{-1}y}{1+y^2}dy
=-\frac43\cdot \frac12 (\tan^{-1}y)^2\bigg|_0^\infty=-\frac{\pi^2}6
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}
\dd x} =
\left.\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\epsilon\, - 1}
\bracks{\pars{1 - x}^{\mu} - 1}\dd x
\right\vert_{\substack{\epsilon\ =\ 0^{+}\\[1mm] \mu\ =\ 0\,\,}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{\epsilon}\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\epsilon + \mu + 1}} - {1 \over \epsilon}}
_{\substack{\epsilon\ =\ 0^{+}\\[1mm] \mu\ =\ 0\,\,}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\partiald{}{\mu}\braces{{1 \over \epsilon}\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{1 + \epsilon}\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\epsilon + \mu + 1}} - 1}}
_{\substack{\epsilon\ =\ 0^{+}\\[1mm] \mu\ =\ 0\,\,}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\left.-\,\partiald{H_{\mu}}{\mu}
\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ 0} = \bbx{\color{#44f}{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 6}}}
\approx -1.6449 \\ &
\end{align}