# Prove that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{e^{\pi x}-1}\mathrm{d}x \in \mathbb{Q}, \forall \,n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

Prove that

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{e^{\pi x}-1}\mathrm{d}x \in \mathbb{Q}, \forall \,n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Comment: This looks like one of Ramanujan’s integrals!

Comment: I suggest you put in some serious effort on $n=1,$  then see what happens with induction. May diverge for $n=0,$ a pity. Meanwhile, where did you get this problem?

Comment: Yet another great question of yours.

Comment: It's alright for $n=0,$ the denominator is $\pi x + more$

Comment: @WillJagy: for $n=0$ Mathematica tells us that the value of the integral is $1/6$.

Comment: @julien: I'm glad you like it. :)

Comment: If you make the change of variables $y=\pi x$ and use the [result](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108248/prove-int-01-frac-ln-x-x-1-sum-1-infty-frac1n2/279065#279065) you get the value of the integral directly.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: that's good point! Thanks!

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals: You are welcome.

Comment: @Will Jagy: the problem is created by Chris. Actually, he experimentally noticed this strange behaviour of the integral and asked me to come up with a solution, but I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an supplement of rlgordonma's answer if one doesn't want to use Bernoulli's numbers.

Start with Euler's infinite product expansion of $\sin(x)$:
$$\sin(x) = x \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - (\frac{x}{k\pi})^2\right)$$
We have for $|x| < \pi$,
$$
\log \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \log( 1 - (\frac{x}{k\pi})^2 )
= - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}(\frac{x}{k\pi})^{2n}\tag{*}$$
Since the double series converges absolutely for $|x| < \pi$, we can switch the order of summation:
$$(*) = - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{x}{k\pi})^{2n} =
-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2n)}{n}(\frac{x}{\pi})^{2n}\tag{**}
$$
We can also differentiate the result term by term to get:
$$\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} - \frac{1}{x} = -2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}} x^{2n-1}$$
In the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, their coefficients are all rational numbers. This mean when we expand L.H.S as a power series in $x$, all its coefficients are rational numbers too. Compare it with those in R.H.S, we get $\frac{\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}}$ are rational numbers for all $n$.

Comment: Very nice (+1) Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Rewrite the integral as

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} dx \: x^{2 n+1} e^{-\pi x} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{- k \pi x} &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} dx \: x^{2 n+1} e^{-(k+1) \pi x}\\ &= \frac{(2 n+1)!}{\pi^{2 n+2}} \zeta(2 n+2)\end{align}$$

(in the last step, I evaluated the integral and the sum produced a Riemann zeta).  We know that, for a zeta of an even integer is

$$\zeta(2 n+2) = (-1)^n \frac{B_{2 n+2} (2 \pi)^{2 n+2}}{2 (2 n+2)!}$$

where $B_k$ is the $k$-th Bernoulli number and is rational.  Putting the last two equations together, it is clear that the sought integral is rational for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: There's always another way to solve these problems.  This is just the one that came to mind right now.  To be honest, I cannot think of another way, but it surely exists.

Comment: OK! Thank you for your work.

Comment: Too bad I have no more upvotes for you left today.

Comment: @julien: me neither.  But some problems I am compelled to solve.

Comment: @rlgordonma: I just put a hyphen between ‘$ k $’ and ‘th’ to improve readability. :)

Comment: @HaskellCurry: not how I normally write things, but OK, thanks for reading that closely.

Comment: Very good idea for using the Bernoulli identity.