# Find the value of: $ J=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^3}{e^x-1}\ln(x)\,dx $

Tags: integration, riemann-zeta

I'm trying to find to value of:
$$
J=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^3}{e^x-1}\ln(x)\,dx
$$

Here's what I've done:

$$
\ln(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}(x-1)^n=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{n\choose m} (-1)^{n-m}x^m
$$
Therefore:
$$
J=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{n\choose m} (-1)^{n-m}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m+3}}{e^x-1}\,dx \\= -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{n\choose m} (-1)^{n-m} \Gamma(m+4) \zeta(m+4)\\
= -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{n\choose m} (-1)^{m}(m+3)! \zeta(m+4)\\
=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n-1)!\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{(n-m)!}(m+3)(m+2)(m+1) \zeta(m+4)\\
$$
And I'm stuck. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great. Mathematica gives the answer as $\frac{\pi^4}{90}(11-6\gamma)+6\zeta'(4)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108248/prove-int-01-frac-ln-x-x-1-sum-1-infty-frac1n2/279065#279065). Here is a solution based on the well known result

$$ \zeta(s)\Gamma(s)= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\,dx \implies \frac{d}{ds}(\zeta(s)\Gamma(s))= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1} \ln(x)}{e^x-1}\,dx $$

So, your integral can be evaluated by taking $s=4$ after performing the derivative with respect to $s$, that is

$$ \frac{d}{ds}(\zeta(s)\Gamma(s))|_{s=4}= 6\,\zeta'\left( 4 \right) +\frac{{\pi }^{4}}{15}\, \left( {\frac {11}{6}}-
\gamma \right).$$

**Added:** To evaluate $\Gamma'(x)$, recall the fact

$$ \psi(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)},$$

which implies

$$\Gamma'(x)=\Gamma(x)\psi(x). $$

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much. The value of $\Gamma'(4)$ wasn't immediately obvious to me, but I was able to figure it out.

Comment: @Mr.G: You are very welcome.

Comment: @Mr.G: You can use the identity $\Gamma'(s)=\Gamma(s)\psi(s)$ to evaluate $\Gamma'(s)$.

Comment: lol ... you always manage to find related problem (+1)