# Show the infinite sum is an integral

Tags: integration, summation

Here is a prelim question that I have not been able to solve:

Show that if $a>1$, then 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/2}a^{-n} = 1/\sqrt{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{y^{-1/2}}{ae^y-1}dy
$$

Thanks so much, it has been driving me crazy!

Comment: There is something wrong with that. There is a "loose" $\sqrt n$ on the right hand side.

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Comment: See [here for the technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108248/prove-int-01-frac-ln-x-x-1-sum-1-infty-frac1n2/279065#279065).

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\dfrac1{ae^y-1} = \dfrac1{ae^y} \dfrac1{1-\dfrac{e^{-y}}{a}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-(k+1)y}}{a^{k+1}}$$
Hence,
$$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{y^{-1/2}}{ae^y-1} dy = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1{a^{k+1}} \int_0^{\infty} y^{-1/2} e^{-(k+1)y} dy$$Now use the $\Gamma$ function and finish it off. Equivalently, use the Gaussian integral, i.e., $$\int_0^{\infty} \exp(-x^2) dx = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}2$$
Using above and some algebraic massaging gives us,
$$\int_0^{\infty} y^{-1/2} e^{-(k+1)y} dy = \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{k+1}}$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{y^{-1/2}}{ae^y-1} dy = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^{-k}}{\sqrt{k}} $$

Comment: You were quicker.