# Integral $\int_0^1 \log x \frac{(1+x^2)x^{c-2}}{1-x^{2c}}dx=-\left(\frac{\pi}{2c}\right)^2\sec ^2 \frac{\pi}{2c}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Hi I am trying to prove this result $$
I:=\int_0^1 \log x \frac{(1+x^2)x^{c-2}}{1-x^{2c}}dx=-\left(\frac{\pi}{2c}\right)^2\sec ^2 \frac{\pi}{2c},\quad c>1.
$$

Thanks.  Since $x\in[0,1]
$ we can write$$
I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 \log x (1+x^2) x^{c-2+2cn}dx.
$$
since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n= (1-x)^{-1} , |x| < 1.$  Simplifying
$$
I=\sum_n \int_0^1 \log x\, x^{c-2+2n} dx+\sum_n \int_0^1 \log x \, x^{c+2cn}\, dx.
$$
Now we can write
$$
I=-\frac{1}{4}\psi_1 \left(\frac{c+1}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{4} \psi_1\left( \frac{3+c}{2}\right)
$$
where I summed the results of the integrals using general result of $\int_0^1 \log x \, x^n \, dx=-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$.  Howeever this is not the result $\sec^2...$.  Thanks

The function $\psi$ is the polygamma function which is defined in general by
$$
\psi_m(z)=\frac{d^{m+1}}{dz^{m+1}} \log \Gamma(z)
$$
and $\Gamma(z)=(z-1)!$, for this case $m=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another derivation that uses only very elementary complex analysis and no special functions:
(all integrals are to be regarded as Cauchy PV integrals if necessary)

By substituting $x\mapsto 1/x$, we find that the original integral equals
$$\int_1^{\infty} (-\log x)  \frac{(1+1/x^2)x^{2-c}}{1-x^{-2c}}\frac{dx}{x^2} = \int_1^{\infty} \log x \frac{(1+x^2)x^{c-2}}{1-x^{2c}} \,dx$$
Adding both copies of the integral, the problem is reduced to showing that
$$\int_0^{\infty} \log x \frac{(1+x^2)x^{c-2}}{1-x^{2c}} \,dx = -\frac{\pi^2}{2c^2}\sec^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2c}\right)$$
We will do this by the method that is by now well-known: let $I(\mu) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{(1+x^2)x^{c-2+\mu}}{1-x^{2c}} \,dx$, then we are looking for $I'(0)$.

We have (remember we are taking PV everywhere)$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{1-x^b} \,dx = \frac{\pi}{b}\cot\left(\pi\frac{a+1}{b}\right)$$
which can be easily derived using residues. (Integrate around a pizza slice contour.)

This immediately gives $$I(\mu) = \frac{\pi}{2c} \left[\cot\left(\pi\frac{c-1+\mu}{2c}\right) + \cot\left(\pi\frac{c+1+\mu}{2c}\right)  \right]$$
and hence 
$$ I'(\mu) = -\frac{\pi^2}{4c^2}\left[\csc^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2c} (c-1+\mu)\right) +\csc^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2c}(c+1+\mu)\right)\right]$$
$$ \implies I'(0) = -\frac{\pi^2}{2c^2}\sec^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2c}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks again for your solutions to my problems...+1

Comment: @Integrals It is my pleasure. This one was a bit easy though, post some harder ones ;)

Comment: Okay :)  The reason I do not post real hard ones as much is because a lot of people seem to complain when I do so.  So I have been making the integrals cleaner and simpler...But I will now for you.

Comment: @Integrals People complain only when you post integrals that are literally unsolvable in terms of known functions. Please make sure they do have a known solution, or conjecture a solution e.g. by numerical calculations.

Comment: all Integrals I post have closed form solutions and I have proofs of every single one them.  They are not "unsolvable"

Comment: @Integrals Ok, very well then.

Answer (score 6):

Using the identity
\begin{align}
\psi(1-x) - \psi(x) = \pi \cot(\pi x)
\end{align}
then the derivative with respect to $x$ yields
\begin{align}
\psi_{1}(1-x) + \psi_{1}(x) = \pi^{2} \csc^{2}(\pi x).
\end{align}
Now the integral
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{ x^{c-2} (1+x^{2}) \ln(x) }{ 1 - x^{2c} } \, dx
\end{align}
is evaluate as follows.
\begin{align}
I &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \, \int_{0}^{1} (1+x^{2}) \, x^{2cn+c-2} \ln(x) \, dx \\
&= - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{1}{(2cn+c-1)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(2cn+c+1)^{2}} \right] \\
&= - \frac{1}{4 c^{2}} \left[ \psi_{1}\left(\frac{c-1}{2c}\right) + \psi_{1}\left( \frac{c+1}{2c}\right) \right] \\
&= - \left(\frac{\pi}{2c}\right)^{2} \csc^{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2c}\right) \\
&= - \left(\frac{\pi}{2c}\right)^{2} \sec^{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2c}\right).  
\end{align}
It can now be stated that
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{ x^{c-2} (1+x^{2}) \ln(x) }{ 1 - x^{2c} } \, dx = - \left(\frac{\pi}{2c}\right)^{2} \sec^{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2c}\right).
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\,{\pars{1 + x^{2}}x^{c - 2} \over 1 - x^{2c}}\,\dd x
     =-\pars{\pi \over 2c}^{2}\sec^{2}\pars{\pi \over 2c}:\ {\large ?}}$

> With $\ds{x \equiv t^{1/\pars{2c}}\quad\imp\quad t = x^{2c}}$:
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\,{\pars{1 + x^{2}}x^{c - 2} \over 1 - x^{2c}}\,\dd x}
> =\int_{0}^{1}
> \ln\pars{t^{1/\bracks{2c}}}\,{\pars{1 + t^{1/c}}t^{1/2 - 1/c} \over 1 - t}
> \,{1 \over 2c}\,t^{1/\pars{2c} - 1}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 4c^{2}}\bracks{%
> \int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{t}t^{-\pars{1 + 1/c}/2} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
> +\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{t}t^{-\pars{1 - 1/c}/2} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over 4c^{2}}
> \lim_{\mu \to -\pars{1 + 1/c}/2}
> \partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{\mu} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t + \pars{~c \to -c~}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#c00000}{-\,{1 \over 4c^{2}}
> \lim_{\mu \to -\pars{1 + 1/c}/2}
> \partiald{\bracks{\Psi\pars{\mu + 1} + \gamma}}{\mu} + \pars{~c \to -c~}}
> \end{align}
>   where we used the [A&S table identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.3.22}}$. $\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ is the [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) and $\ds{\gamma}$ is the
>   [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm).

\begin{align}
&\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\,{\pars{1 + x^{2}}x^{c - 2} \over 1 - x^{2c}}\,\dd x}
=
-\,{1 \over 4c^{2}}\bracks{\Psi'\pars{\half + {1 \over 2c}} + \Psi'\pars{\half - {1 \over 2c}}}
\end{align}
With [Euler Reflection Formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_260.htm)
${\bf\mbox{6.4.7}}$:
\begin{align}
&\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\,{\pars{1 + x^{2}}x^{c - 2} \over 1 - x^{2c}}\,\dd x}
=
-\,{1 \over 4c^{2}}\bracks{-\pi\,\totald{\cot\pars{\pi z}}{z}}
_{z\ =\ 1/2\ -\ 1/\pars{2c}}
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\pi^{2} \over 4c^{2}}\,\csc^{2}\pars{\pi\bracks{\half - {1 \over 2c}}}
=-\,{\pi^{2} \over 4c^{2}}\,\sec^{2}\pars{\pi \over 2c}
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#00f}{\large%
> \int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\,{\pars{1 + x^{2}}x^{c - 2} \over 1 - x^{2c}}\,\dd x}
> =\color{#00f}{\large-\,\pars{\pi \over 2c}^{2}\sec^{2}\pars{\pi \over 2c}}\,,\qquad
> \verts{c} > 1
> $$

Comment: @Integrals You're welcome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach. Follow the steps

1) Make the change of variables $\ln(x)=-t$

2) Follow it with another change of variables $y=2ct$

3) Use the Hurwitz Zeta function. See this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385862/evaluating-int-0-infty-big-fracxa-1-sinh-x-xa-2-big-dx/385918#385918).