# How to find this integral $\int_{0}^{1}\ln\ln\bigl(1/x+\sqrt{(1/x^2)-1}\,\bigr)dx$

Tags: integration

> How do I compute this integral ?
>
> $$I=\int_{0}^{1}\ln{\left(\ln{\left(\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}\right)}\right)}dx$$

In the math [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16630188#16630188) someone suggests setting $x=\operatorname{sech}(t)$ and that the result immediately follows.

I don't agree with it

because
$$\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}=\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}+\sqrt{\cosh^2{t}-1}=e^t$$
and $$dx=\frac{e^t}{(e^{2t}+1)^2}dt$$

so
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(t)\frac{e^{t}}{(e^{2t}+1)^2}dt$$
Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK you do not agree. Nice to know. But why? And what do you suggest instead?

Comment: because this two $ln(ln())$

Comment: why closed? Thank you

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Please try the change of variable proposes in the chatroom and show us that it gives nothing.

Comment: @user37238,hello,you can go in the room see it

Comment: What if I do not want to go and visit the chatroom? Please make your question self-contained. (Actually I did go to the chatroom, first return after a long period of absence, and well... one cannot recommand the experience.)

Comment: @Did,Because I don't want to say which person.and second I want introduce this room.

Comment: .and I hope @Did can in this room to discuss

Comment: Voted to reopen. After the additions you made, I think this should be put on hold as duplicate, not anymore as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: I think `\dfrac` should not be used in titles. See: [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles}(http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles)

Comment: @Martin I think `\dfrac` should not be used, other than in [exceptional circumstances](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12978/should-dfrac-be-edited-in)!

Comment: (Also, I should say that `\dfrac` and `\frac` render the same in this post, because the fractions are taking new lines.)

Answer (score 1):

Your derivative is not correct. Actually you should obtain
$$\mathrm{d}x=-\mathrm{sech}(t)\tanh(t)\mathrm{d}t\,.$$
Your integral then becomes
$$I=-\int_\infty^0\log(t)\mathrm{sech}(t)\tanh(t)\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^\infty\log(t)\mathrm{sech}(t)\tanh(t)\mathrm{d}t\,.$$

This is still not a trivial integral, but Mathematica tells me that it is
$$I=-\gamma +\log \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)-2 \log \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)+\log \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)\right)\approx 0.205973\,. $$
Here, $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) and $\Gamma$ is the usual [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: You can use the Hurwitz zeta function to evaluate the integral. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385862/evaluating-int-0-infty-big-fracxa-1-sinh-x-xa-2-big-dx/385918#385918).