# Integral of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, integration, definite-integrals

I cannot solve this integral, can anyone help me?

$$\int_0^\infty \left(x^3 \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} e^{-nx} \right)dx$$

Thank you in advance

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108248/prove-int-01-frac-ln-x-x-1-d-x-sum-1-infty-frac1n2/279065#279065).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the change variable $t=nx$ we have
$$\int_0^\infty x^3e^{-nx}dx=\frac{1}{n^4}\int_0^\infty t^3e^{-t}dt=\frac{\Gamma(4)}{n^4}$$
so
$$\int_0^\infty (x^3 \sum_{1}^ \infty e^{-nx})dx=\Gamma(4) \sum_{1}^ \infty\frac{1}{n^4}=\Gamma(4)\zeta(4)=3!\times \frac{\pi^4}{90}$$

Comment: Could you please specify the integral in the variable t?

Comment: Yes I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! How did you calculate the value of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}$?

Comment: You can calculate the Fourier series of the periodic function $|x|$ on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ and then apply the Parseval theorem.

Comment: or using complex analysis or bernoulli numbers ..