# Integrate $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(x)}{x+1} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How can I integrate this?  $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(x)}{x+1} dx $

I've seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108248/prove-int-01-frac-ln-x-x-1-d-x-sum-1-infty-frac1n2)  but I failed to apply it on my problem.

Could you give some hint?

EDIT : From hint of @H.H.Rugh, I've got $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^2}$, since $\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\ln(x)dx = (-1)\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$. How can I proceed this calculation hereafter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3...$ Then integrate term by term using partial integration.

Comment: Thank you, I've got the answer $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{1}{n^2}$. Could you give hints that how can I calculate this sum?

Comment: You then use  $(1-\frac{2}{2^2}) (1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2} ...) = 1-\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}-...$ and you probably recognize the first series.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I didn't know the last formula.

Comment: Decompose it into the sum over even-indexed terms and the sum over odd-indexed terms. Both sums can be found pretty immediately if you know $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

You can derivate $Li_2(-x)+(\ln x)(\ln (x+1))+C$ where $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dz}Li_2(z)=-\frac{\ln(1-z)}{z}$ and you will see how to integrate.

Hint: $\displaystyle\enspace Li_s(z):=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k^s}$ and $\displaystyle\enspace Li_2(1)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ .