# Is the integral $\int_1^\infty\frac{x^{-a} - x^{-b}}{\log(x)}\,dx$ convergent?

Tags: measure-theory, integration

Is the integral $$\int_1^\infty\frac{x^{-a} - x^{-b}}{\log(x)}\,dx$$ convergent, where $b>a>1$?

I think the answer lies in defining a double integral with $yx^{(-y-1)}$ and applying Tonelli's Theorem, but the integral of $\frac{x^{-a}}{\log x}$ is still not integrable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we make substitution $x=\log t$, then we get integral  of the form
$$
\int\limits_{0}^\infty\frac{e^{-(a-1)t}-e^{-(b-1)t}}{t}dt
$$
Now result follows from [Frullani's integral formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) applied to the function $f(t) = e^{-t}$. Moreover, this formula gives us exact value of the integral
$$
\int\limits_{0}^\infty\frac{e^{-(a-1)t}-e^{-(b-1)t}}{t}dt=(f(0)-f(\infty))\log\frac{b-1}{a-1}=\log\frac{b-1}{a-1}
$$

As for the proof of this formula see [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/frullani-proof-integrals).