# Evaluate $\int_0^1\frac{x^3 - x^2}{\ln x}\,\mathrm dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How do I evaluate the following integral?

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^3 - x^2}{\ln x }\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrate $\int_0^1 {\frac {x^a-x^b} {\ln x} dx}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781033/integrate-int-01-frac-xa-xb-ln-x-dx) or see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100495/showing-that-int-01-fracx-1-lnx-mathrm-dt-ln2?lq=1. There are many questions like this, but this one is yours?

Comment: Substitute $x = \exp(-t)$ and we get [Frullani's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154881/is-the-integral-int-1-infty-fracx-a-x-b-logx-dx-convergent

Answer (score 22):

Sub $x=e^{-u}$, $dx = -e^{-u} du$.  Then the integral is

$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{x^3-x^2}{\log{x}} = \int_0^{\infty} du \, \frac{e^{-3 u} - e^{-4 u}}{u} = \int_0^{\infty} du \,  \int_3^4 dt \, e^{-u t} \\  = \int_3^4 dt \,\int_0^{\infty} du \, e^{-u t} = \int_3^4 \frac{dt}{t} = \log{\frac{4}{3}}$$

The change in the order of integration is justified by Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: Whey are your $du$'s in front of your integrand?

Comment: @AlexYoucis: It is a habit I got from physics.  Note that it helps sort out the double integrals.

Comment: IMHO it also feels better, as it makes $\int_a^b dx$ look like an operator acting on a function on the right side :)

Comment: That notation ($du$ first) is very old-fashioned...but we humor Ron here, because he has such good answers.

Comment: @GEdgar: Nice to know I have earned my eccentricity.  Thanks.

Comment: @RonGordon: to say that your eccentricity is greater than $1$ would be hyperbolic.

Answer (score 11):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{x^3-x^2}{\log(x)}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\frac{x^4-x^3}{\log(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\\
&=\lim_{a\to0}\int_a^1\frac{x^4-x^3}{\log(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\\
&=\lim_{a\to0}\left(\int_a^1\frac{x^4-1}{\log(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}
-\int_a^1\frac{x^3-1}{\log(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\right)\\
&=\lim_{a\to0}\left(\int_{a^4}^1\frac{x-1}{\log(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}
-\int_{a^3}^1\frac{x-1}{\log(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\right)\\
&=\lim_{a\to0}\int_{a^4}^{a^3}\frac{x-1}{\log(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\\
&=\lim_{a\to0}\int_{a^4}^{a^3}\frac1{\log(x)}\mathrm{d}x
-\lim_{a\to0}\int_{a^4}^{a^3}\frac1{\log(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\\
&=0-\Big[\log(\log(x))\Big]_{a^4}^{a^3}\\[6pt]
&=\log(4)-\log(3)\\[12pt]
&=\log(4/3)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I like how you find interesting nonstandard ways to evaluate integrals and sums. But why does $\lim_{a \to 0} \int_{a^{4}}^{a^{3}} \frac{dx}{\log x} \ dx = 0$? Is it because $\frac{1}{\log x}$ is continuous at $x=0$?

Comment: @RandomVariable: it is because the interval is very small, less than $a^3$ in length, and the integrand is very small on that interval, less than $\frac1{3|\log(a)|}$ in absolute value.

Comment: My initial thought was that the integrand of the first integral is continuous on that interval while the integrand of the second integral is unbounded on that interval. That's not sufficient reasoning to conclude that the first integral goes to zero and the second integral doesn't? The integrand needs to be very small as well?

Comment: @RandomVariable: There are two reasons: 1. the interval is very small and the integrand is bounded; 2. the interval is bounded and the integrand is very small. Either will ensure that the integral is very small, and both are applicable here.

Comment: My reasoning was basically the first reason (with the unnecessary addition of continuity). Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{x^3-x^2}{\ln x }\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\frac{x^3-1-x^2+1}{\ln x }\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{x^\color{blue}{3}-1}{\ln x }\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^1\frac{x^\color{red}{2}-1}{\ln x}\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=\ln(\color{blue}{3}+1)-\ln(\color{red}{2}+1)\tag{3}\\
&=\ln\frac43\tag{4}\\
\end{align}$$

> $$\large\int_0^1\frac{x^3-x^2}{\log(x)}\mathrm{d}x=\ln\frac43$$

---

$\text{Explanation : } (3
)$

Consider parametric integral $\displaystyle\quad\quad\quad 
I(\alpha)=\int_0^1{\frac{x^{\alpha}-1}{\ln x}\mathrm dx}$

We have $I(0)=0$, By differentiating w.r.t $\alpha$ we get

$$
I'(\alpha)
=\int_0^1{\frac{x^{\alpha}\ln x}{\ln x}\,\mathrm dx}
=\int_0^1{x^{\alpha}\,\mathrm dx}
=\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}
=\frac{1}{\alpha+1}$$
Integrating w.r.t. $\alpha$ and using $I(0)=0$ we get
$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^1{\frac{x^{\alpha}-1}{\ln x}\,\mathrm dx}=\ln(\alpha+1)$$

Comment: The so-called "Feynman's trick" comes through!  Gotta love Richard.  +1

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{3} - x^{2} \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
=\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{2} - x^{3}}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{t}\,\dd t}^{\dsc{-\,{1 \over \ln\pars{x}}}}\
\,\dd x\ =\
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{2 + t} - x^{3 + t}}\,\dd x\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over t + 3} - {1 \over t + 4}}\,\dd t
=\left.\ln\pars{t + 3 \over t + 4}\right\vert_{\, t\ =\ 0}^{\, t\ \to\ \infty}
=-\ln\pars{3 \over 4}=\color{#66f}{\large\ln\pars{4 \over 3}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

You may like this method. Note
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} n(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)=\ln x, \text{ for }x>0 $$
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1\frac{x^3-x^2}{\ln x}dx&=&\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^3-x^2}{n(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)}dx\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{x^2(x-1)}{n(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)}dx\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1x^2\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{\frac{k}{n}}dx\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{\frac{k}{n}+2}dx\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\frac{k}{n}+3}\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{1}{x+3}dx\\
&=&\ln\frac{4}{3}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Now that was clever!  +1  What prompted this approach?

Comment: @Dr.MV, I saw other people using this approach before in some where.

Comment: Well then, very well done!

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$$I = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2(x - 1)}{\log(x)}$$

Consider:

$$I(b) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^b(x - 1)}{\log(x)}$$

Recognize that $I(0) = \int_{0}^{1} (x-1)/\log(x) dx = \log(2)$, this is a particular solution for later.

Differentiate partially with respect to $b$

$$I'(b) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(x)\cdot x^b(x - 1)}{\log(x)} dx$$

$$I'(b) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^b(x - 1)}{1} dx = \int_{0}^{1} x^b(x - 1) dx $$

$$I'(b) = \int_{0}^{1} x^{b+1} - x^b dx$$

$$I'(b) = \frac{1}{b+2} - \frac{1}{b+1}$$

Integrate this with respect to $db$

$$I(b) = \int \frac{1}{b+2} - \frac{1}{b+1} db$$

$$I(b) = \log(b+2) - \log(b+1) + C$$

$C= 0$

$$I(2) = \log(4) -  \log(3) = \log(4/3)$$