# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2015}-1}{\ln x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2015}-1}{\ln x}dx\;\;$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$I(a) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{a}-1}{\ln x}dx\;,$$ Then $$I'(a) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^a\cdot \ln(x)}{\ln(x)}dx = \int_{0}^{1}x^{a}dx = \left[\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}\right]_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{a+1}$$

So we get $$I(a) = \ln|a+1|+\mathcal{C}.$$

Now When $a=0\;,$ We get $I(0) =0$

So we get $I(0)=\ln(1)+\mathcal{C}\Rightarrow 0 = 0+\mathcal{C}\Rightarrow \mathcal{C}=0$

So we get $$I(a) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{a}-1}{\ln(x)}dx = \ln|a+1|$$

So $$I(2015) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2015}-1}{\ln(x)}dx = \ln|2016|$$

can we solve it by using any other Method Like Using Double Integration.

If yes Then plz explain here, Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand the 2nd step...how did you compute $I'(a)$?

Comment: Actually above we have differentiate w r. to $a$ . So above $a$ is variable and $x$ is Constant.

Comment: Sub $x=e^{-u}$ and get a Frullani integral.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701557/evaluate-int-01-fracx3-x2-ln-x-mathrm-dx/701568#701568

Comment: Looks OK to me; also, it looks quite natural to solve it this way. As to any other method... well, surely some must be possible, but why bother. Any other answer would be either wrong or the same as this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may consider the double integral
$$
I:=\int_0^1\!\!\int_0^1a\:x^{ay} dx\:dy,\qquad a\geq0.
$$ Applying Fubini's theorem, on the one hand, we have
$$
I=\int_0^1\!\left(\int_0^1a\:x^{ay} dy\right)dx=\int_0^1\frac{x^a-1}{\ln x}\:dx.
$$ On the other hand,$$
I=\int_0^1\!\left(\int_0^1a\:x^{ay} dx\right)dy= \int_0^1\!\!\frac{a}{ay+1}dy=\int_0^1\frac{(ay+1)'}{ay+1}dy=\ln(a+1).
$$ Thus

> $$
> \int_0^1\frac{x^a-1}{\ln x}dx=\ln(a+1),\qquad a\geq0.
> $$

Then we put $a:=2015$ to obtain the initial integral.