# Evaluation of the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos6t-\cos4t}{t}\text{d}t$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I need help calculating the following improper integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos6t-\cos4t}{t}\text{d}t$$

I tried using substitutions and expansions for the cosine function, but nothing worked. The answer is supposed to be $\ln(2/3)$.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267671/about-frullani-integral

Comment: This boils down to a difference of Cosine Integrals, denoted $$\int_x^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{t}dt = \text{Ci}(x)$$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral I don't imagine this is a trivial integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the integral identity 
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{f(at)-f(bt)}{t}dt=f(0)\ln(\frac{b}{a}),~a,b>0
$$
for $a=6$ and $b=4$ which gives the answer. This is called Frullani's theorem. For a proof, see the following:

[Proof of Frullani's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/proof-of-frullanis-theorem)

Comment: If that's true +1. To show me its true, post a link to a proof or something.

Comment: look at @FH93 comment for example

Comment: I think it is called Frullani's theorem. Here is a paper
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1990-109-01/S0002-9939-1990-1007485-4/S0002-9939-1990-1007485-4.pdf

Comment: Doesn't this identity require that $\lim_{x\to\infty} h(x) = 0$?

Comment: @George thanks for the link and also thanks tired.

Comment: I think you need $h'(t)/t$to be bounded near the origin, and the condition $\int^{\infty}_{l}h'(t)/t dt<\infty,~l>0$ to hold.

Comment: @MathManiac I've edited my solution, in which I apply a theorem [An Extended Frullani Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746297/an-extended-frullani-integral).  In that theorem, we see that for $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$, and $F'(0)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{F(x)}x$ exist, then $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x}\,dx=(F'(0) -\bar F_\infty)\log(b/a)$$.

Answer (score 5):

Our integral is just: 
$$ I=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(2t)-\sin^2(3t)}{t}\,dt, $$
so by exploiting:
$$ \mathcal{L}(\sin^2(2t))=\frac{8}{s(s^2+16)},\qquad  \mathcal{L}(\sin^2(3t))=\frac{18}{s(s^2+36)}$$
we have:
$$ I = -\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{20 s\,ds}{(s^2+16)(s^2+36)} = -\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{10\,du}{(u+16)(u+36)}$$
from which $I=\color{red}{\log\frac{2}{3}}$ readily follows by partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: An interesting approach, although it seems that a modified application of Frullani is a bit faster.

Comment: @Dr.MV: I agree with you, I was just showing how the Laplace transform gives an alternative way.

Comment: I think the LT approach is really cool!  Does it still amaze you that analysis is so robust that one can approach a problem in quite distinct ways, all of which, if legitimate, lead to the same answer?  How cool is that?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

Applying [this theorem, An Extended Frullani Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746297/an-extended-frullani-integral), where $f(x)=\cos(x)$, $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$, and $\bar F(x)=\frac1x F(x)$, we find that $F'(0)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} \bar F(x)=0$.  We find immediately that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(6t)-\cos(4t)}{t}\,dt=\log(2/3)$$

And we are done!!

---

---

From [Frullani's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) we have

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x}dx=(f(0)-f(\infty))\log(b/a)$$

Here, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(6x)-\cos(4x)}{x}dx&=\text{Re}\left(\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{(i-\epsilon)6x}-e^{(i-\epsilon)4x}}{x}dx\right)\\\\
&=\text{Re}\left(\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\log(4/6)\right)\\\\
&=\log(2/3)
\end{align}$$

---

**NOTE:**

WE justify the interchange of the limit with the integral in the preceding development by use of [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Statement_of_theorem).  To that end, let $f(z)$ be the given by

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{i6z}-e^{i4z}}{z}$$

and note that $f$ is analytic with a removable discontinuity at $z=0$.  Thus, we have for any simply connected contour $C$

$$\oint_C f(z)\,dz=0$$

We choose $C$ to be the contour with the following $3$ segments

$(i)$  The line segment $C_1$ along the positive real axis from $(0,0)$ to $(R,0)$

$(ii)$  The line segment $C_2$ from $(R/\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2},R\epsilon/\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2})$ to $(0,0)$

and

$(iii)$ The circular arc $C_R$ of radius $R$ that goes from $(R,0)$ to $(R/\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2},R\epsilon/\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2})$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C f(z)\,dz&=\oint_C \frac{e^{i6z}-e^{i4z}}{z}dz\\\\
&=\int_{C_1}\frac{e^{i6z}-e^{i4z}}{z}dz+\int_{C_2}\frac{e^{i6z}-e^{i4z}}{z}dz+\int_{C_R}\frac{e^{i6z}-e^{i4z}}{z}dz\\\\
&=\int_0^R \frac{e^{i6x}-e^{i4x}}{x}\,dx\\\\
&-\int_0^{R/\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2}} \frac{e^{6x(i-\epsilon)}-e^{4x(i-\epsilon)}}{x}\,dx\\\\
&+i\,\int_0^{\arctan(\epsilon)}\left(e^{i6Re^{i\theta}}-e^{i4Re^{i\theta}}\right)d\theta \tag 1\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

As $R\to \infty$ the last integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ approaches $0$ as $O(R^{-1})$ by [Jordan's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma#Statement).  Thus, we have

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{i6x}-e^{i4x}}{x}\,dx=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{6x(i-\epsilon)}-e^{4x(i-\epsilon)}}{x}\,dx$$

for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Good to realize Frullani requires convergence of $f$ at intinity.  I assume that's why you moved off the real axis.  But now: how to justify interchanging integral and limit?

Comment: @GEdgar That's an easy one. Use Cauchy's Integral Theorem.

Comment: @GEdgar I edited and added a Note section that validates the interchange of limit and integral.  In fact, the two quantities are equal before taking the limit!   It is simply a deformation of path in the complex plane.  But I really thought it was evident upon my original post.

Comment: I think $e^{6Re^{i\theta}}$ should be $e^{6iRe^{i\theta}}$ etc.

Comment: @J.G. Ah yes.  Indeed.  Great catch! (+1)  And Happy New Year my friend.

Comment: @GEdgar Happy New Year!  Actually, in [this Extended Frullani Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746297/an-extended-frullani-integral), we only need that $F'(0)$ and $\bar F_\infty$ exist.  Then, $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x}\,dx=(F'(0)-\bar f_\infty)\log(b/a)$$I've edited my original solution and added this way forward.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_0^∞(\cos(6t)-\cos(4t))/t²dt=\int_0^∞(\cos(6t)-1)/t²dt-\int_0^∞(\cos(6t)-1)/t²dt=\\-2\int_0^∞\sin²(12t)/t²dt+2\int_0^∞\sin²(8t)/t²$$dt. Changing variables $12t->u,8t->v$ gives $$I=-8\int_0^∞sin²(t)/t²dt.$$The last integral is well-known either by residues or by Fourier's Transform.

Comment: what is that?!?

Comment: learn $tex$ please, i fixed it this time!

Comment: btw. the above would yield a value of the integral of $-4 \pi$ which definitely wrong!

Comment: @Adelafif: You should be dividing by $t$ and not by $t^2$. That is why it yields a wrong answer.