# Definite integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^4(7x)-\sin^4(5x)}{x} \ \mathrm d x$

Tags: definite-integrals

Find the definite integral of:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^4(7x)-\sin^4(5x)}{x} \ \mathrm d x$$

This question is from a Belarusian mathematical olympiad. This is from the topic of definite integrals, but I can't think of anything.

I tried using the Newton-Leibniz rule which we use generally to solve such questions. But it did not work. Please help.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Please show us your working and see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Looks like a Frullani integral.

Comment: I tried keeping sin⁴(7x) as sin⁴(tx) and differentiating both sides.

Comment: Can you show us your steps (that you have worked out), and add that to the question? You might be able to use the Laplace transform as shown in [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322724/evaluation-of-the-improper-integral-int-0-infty-frac-cos6t-cos4tt-te).

Comment: Sorry not able to add my works picture it needs reputation points . But its not what angina seng is saying because its applicable for function which with limit x-> infinity exists but in our case we can't say that.

Comment: Also toby mak i dont know laplace transform i think it may help ill see it.

Comment: I dont know maybe iil try.

Comment: Ok it worked it converted into that form metamorphy and angina seng i applied frullanis integral theorem.

Comment: Thankyou all of you.

Comment: @Obsessedwithintegrals if you can, try writing an answer for this question on your own. It will help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note $\sin^4(kx )= \frac38 +\frac18\cos (4kx) -\frac12 \cos(2kx)$. Then,

\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^4(7x)-\sin^4(5x)}{x}dx\\
=&\frac18\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(28x)-\cos(20x)}{x}dx
-\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(14x)-\cos(10x)}{x}dx\\
= &(\frac18-\frac12)\ln\frac57=\frac38\ln\frac75
\end{align}

where the result $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx )}{x}dx=\ln\frac b a$is used.

[Finding $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3358742/finding-int-0-infty-frac-cosax-cosbxxdx/3358783#3358783)

Comment: Yes this is what used. I am an high school so i think this is the approach I should follow.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following equality in order to compute the integral:

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\mathcal{L\{f(t)\}}\,\mathrm{d}s
\end{equation}

Then:

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}(7t)-\sin^{4}(4t)}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\mathcal{L}\{\sin^{4}(7t)\}\,\mathrm{d}s-\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\mathcal{L}\{\sin^{4}(4t)\}\,\mathrm{d}s
\end{equation}

Knowing that:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}\{\sin^{4}(7t)\}=\frac{57624}{s(s^{4}+980s^{2}+153664)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}\{\sin^{4}(4t)\}=\frac{6144}{s(s^{4}+320s^{2}+16384)}
\end{equation}

Thus:

\begin{equation}
I=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{57624}{s(s^{4}+980s^{2}+153664)}\mathrm{d}s-\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{6144}{s(s^{4}+320s^{2}+16384)}\mathrm{d}s
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\Biggl[\frac{57624}{s(s^{4}+980s^{2}+153664)}-\frac{6144}{s(s^{4}+320s^{2}+16384)}\Biggr]\mathrm{d}s
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\Biggl[\frac{57624s(s^{4}+320s^{2}+16384)-6144s(s^{4}+980s^{2}+153664)}{s^{2}(s^{4}+980s^{2}+153664)(s^{4}+320s^{2}+16384)}\Biggr]\mathrm{d}s
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I=3960\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s(13s^{2}+3136)}{(s^{2}+64)(s^{2}+196)(s^{2}+256)(s^{2}+784)}\mathrm{d}s
\end{equation}

With $u=s^{2}$, you arrive at the following:

\begin{equation}
I=1980\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(13u+3136)}{(u+64)(u+196)(u+256)(u+784)}\mathrm{d}u
\end{equation}

This last integral is quite tedious but doable with standard methods:

\begin{equation}
1980\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(13u+3136)}{(u+64)(u+196)(u+256)(u+784)}\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{8}\ln\left(\frac{343}{64}\right)
\end{equation}

Thus:

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}(7t)-\sin^{4}(4t)}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{8}\ln\left(\frac{343}{64}\right)=\frac{3}{8}\ln\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)}
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes luis i think if i would have studied laplace i would have understand your solution but seeing as whole its kind messy.yeah for using frullanis integral we have to prove it for applying on cosx if i am explaining it to a high schooler.but i think its simple than this.but thanks for solution.

Comment: It took time luis but i finally understand your answer.

Comment: Good to know man!