# Solution of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(x)-\arctan(2x)}x\mathrm dx$ : Why Wolfram Alpha shows a different answer than mine?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

For, $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(x)-\arctan(2x)}x \mathrm dx$

Let, $I_1=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{arctan(x)}x\mathrm dx$ and $I_2=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(2x)}x\mathrm dx$

For, $I_1$ let $x=\frac 1u $ so $I_1=\int_{\infty}^{0} \frac{\arctan(\frac1u)}{\frac1u}\left(-\frac1{u^2}\right)\mathrm du$ $=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{arccot(u)}{u}du$

From which it follows, $I_1=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\frac\pi2-\arctan(x)}x\mathrm dx$ So, $2I_1=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\frac \pi2}x\mathrm dx$

In the same way it can be shown that, $2I_2=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\frac\pi2}x\mathrm dx$

So, $2I=2I_1-2I_2=0$

But, Wolfram Alpha says, [image]

So, where is my error?

Comment: Both $I_1$ and $I_2$ are infinite. You can derive all sort of awkward results if you manipulate divergent quantities carelessly.

Comment: I think that $tan^{-1}$ in this case means $cot$, not $arctan$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Can you give me an example?

Comment: @stuartstevenson No; WolframAlpha interprets $\arctan$ as $\tan^{-1}$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+0+to+infinity+1%2Fx+(arctan(x)-arctan(2x))

Comment: You just gave an example of what @SangchulLee meant.

Comment: @ProfessorVector So is my answer wrong?

Comment: To reproduce WA's (correct) result, use [Frullani's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/proof-of-frullanis-theorem) with $f(x)=\arctan x - \pi/2$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460307/evaluate-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-arctan-pi-x-arctan-xxdx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @HansLundmark What's make WA's result correct?

Comment: @Mockingbird360: Just apply the result in the question I linked to, and you'll see that that's what comes out...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460307/evaluate-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-arctan-pi-x-arctan-xxdx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the following erroneous computation:

\begin{align*}
\log 2
&=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\\
&=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)
-2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)\\
&=0.\end{align*}

This mistake is in spirit the same as what you did in your computation.

---

Here is one possible computation. Fix $ R > 0$ and introduce

$$ I_1 = I_1(R) = \int_{0}^{R} \frac{\arctan (x)}{x} \, dx, \qquad I_2 = I_2(R) = \int_{0}^{R} \frac{\arctan (2x)}{x} \, dx. $$

Using the substitution $2x \mapsto x$, we have

$$ I_2 = \int_{0}^{2R} \frac{\arctan x}{x} \, dx $$

and hence

$$ I_1 - I_2
= -\int_{R}^{2R} \frac{\arctan x}{x} \, dx
\stackrel{(x=Rt)}{=} -\int_{1}^{2} \frac{\arctan(Rt)}{t} \, dt. $$

So taking $R \to \infty$, we have

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan x - \arctan (2x)}{x} \, dx
= -\int_{1}^{2} \frac{\pi/2}{x} \, dx
= -\frac{\pi}{2}\log 2. $$

(*Remark.* Of course, interchanging the limit and the integral is in general now allowed. In our case, this is easily justified by the following inequality

$$ \frac{\pi}{2}\arctan(R)
\leq \int_{1}^{2} \frac{\arctan(Rt)}{t} \, dt
\leq \frac{\pi}{2}\arctan(2R). $$

Applying the squeezing lemma indeed establishes the desired convergence.)

Answer (score 6):

Let's start off with
$$\begin{align}I(a)&=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\arctan x-\arctan ax}x\mathrm dx\\I'(a)&=\int_0^\infty-\dfrac1{1+a^2x^2}\mathrm dx\\&=-\dfrac1a\int_0^\infty\dfrac1{1+u^2}\mathrm du\qquad[\text{Taking }u=ax]\\&=-\dfrac1a\arctan(u)\bigg|_0^\infty\\&=-\dfrac\pi{2a}\end{align}$$
And now, we integrate both sides with respect to $a$

$$\begin{align}I'(a)&=-\dfrac\pi{2a}\\I(a)&=-\dfrac\pi2\ln a+C\end{align}$$
At $a=1,C=0$
So,we can write

$$I(a)=-\dfrac\pi2\ln a$$

And hence,

$$\begin{align}I(2)&=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\arctan x-\arctan 2x}x\mathrm dx=-\dfrac\pi2\ln 2\end{align}$$

This is what WolframAlpha gives you.

And if you want, just use **Frullani's integral** which says that
$$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{f(ax)-f(bx)}x\mathrm dx=[f(0)-f(\infty)]\ln\left(\dfrac ba\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

By Fubini's Theorem,
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(x)-\arctan(2x)}x \mathrm dx\\
&=&\int_0^{\infty} \int_1^2\frac{1}{1+t^2x^2}\mathrm dt \mathrm dx\\
&=&\int_1^2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+t^2x^2}\mathrm dx \mathrm dt\\
&=&\int_1^2\frac{\arctan(tx)}{t}\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=\infty}dt\\
&=&\int_1^2\frac{\pi}{2t}dt\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

Not for sure, but when you made $x=1/u$, you cant afirm that $x\to 0$ will $u\to \infty$ (because the negative side) and when substitue for integrating $\displaystyle \int_{\infty}^0 $ thats not a usal think. Maybe, the error is quit up here (our close). Those integrals need a hyred tools, like *dilogarithm* $\displaystyle \Big( \text{Li}_2(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n^2}\Big)$. Try https://www.integral-calculator.com/, they can explain whey better then me.