# Definite integral $\arctan$ over $x$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\arctan(2x)-\arctan(x)}{x }dx$$

I checked that the integral converges. Next, the only thing that seems to appear to me to do is arctan sum formula
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\arctan({x\over{1+2x^2}})}{x }dx$$
but then it's dead end. How do I proceed further?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral

Comment: The answer to the question [Solution of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(x)-\arctan(2x)}x\mathrm dx$ : Why Wolfram Alpha shows a different answer than mine?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579722/solution-of-int-0-infty-frac-arctanx-arctan2xx-mathrm-dx-why-wol) contains a computation that will lead you to the answer. In addition, consider applying Frullani's theorem.