# question over a integration changes order and hard to compute

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to integrate the following function:
$$f(x,y)=xy\times e^{-\frac{x^2y^2}{2}},x\in(1,2), y\in(0,\infty)$$
To do the integration:
$$\int_1^2 \int_0^\infty f(x,y)dydx=\int_1^2\frac{1}{x}dx=\ln 2$$

However, on the other hand, if we do the integration over x first:
$$ \int_0^\infty \int_1^2 f(x,y) dxdy=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{y}(-e^{-2y^2}+e^{-0.5y^2})dy$$
This integration is hard to calculate, since each separate part is divergent, anyone can give a solution to this integration?

Comment: Substitute $t = y^2$ and then use Frullani. But you know the easy way already, so why bother?

Comment: Perform the natural substitution and it falls pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have seen it is sometimes better to integrate with respect to one variable first.

The integral 
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{y}(-e^{-2y^2}+e^{-0.5y^2})\,dy
$$
is a [Frullani integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/proof-of-frullanis-theorem),
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{f(ay)-f(by)}{y}\,dy=f(0)\log(b/a).
$$

In your case $f(y)=e^{-y^2}$, $a=1/\sqrt{2}$, and $b=\sqrt{2}$.