# How to evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos {(ax)}-\cos{(b x)}}{x^2 }dx$?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm wondering how to integrate the so-called integral using Residue theorem,as it has a pole of second order on the real axis(not simple) so we cannot use $\pi i Res(@ z=0)$.Would you please give me a hint?($a,b>0$)

Comment: How about this one?

Comment: Another form is $$-\frac{1}{2}I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}(a+b)x\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}(a-b)x\right)}{x^2}{dx}.$$

Comment: Can you not use a keyhole contour?

Comment: I just want it to be solved!what should we do after this?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828 (but not via residue calculus)

Comment: You can check that now $x=0$ is a simple pole on real-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the integral

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{i a z}-e^{i b z}}{z^2} $$

where $C$ is a semicircle in the upper half plane of radius $R$ with a small semicircular detour at $z=0$ of radius $\epsilon$ into the upper half plane. Then the integral is equal to

$$PV \int_{-R}^R dx \frac{e^{i a x}-e^{i b x}}{x^2} +i R \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{e^{i a R e^{i \theta}} - e^{i b R e^{i \theta}}}{R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}} + i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{e^{i a \epsilon e^{i \phi}} - e^{i b \epsilon e^{i \phi}}}{\epsilon^2 e^{i 2 \phi}}$$

where $PV$ denotes the Cauchy principal value of the integral.

As $R \to \infty$, the second integral vanishes.  This is so because the magnitude of the integral is bounded by

$$\frac1{R} \int_0^{\pi} d\theta  \, e^{-\min{(a,b)} R \sin{\theta} } \le \frac{2}{R} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta  \, e^{-2 \min{(a,b)} R \theta/\pi} \le \frac{\pi}{\min{(a,b)} R^2}$$

We now consider the third integral as $\epsilon \to 0$.  In this case, we Taylor expand the numerator and find that the integral has a limit:

$$i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{i a \epsilon e^{i \phi} - i \epsilon b e^{i \phi}}{\epsilon^2 e^{i 2 \phi}} = -\pi(b-a)$$

By Cauchy's theorem, the contour integral is zero.  Thus, in these limits - and taking the real part of both sides - we find that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{\cos{ax}-\cos{b x}}{x^2} = \pi (b-a) $$

or

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty} dx \frac{\cos{ax}-\cos{b x}}{x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2} (b-a) $$

Comment: I have problem understanding these inequalities$\frac1{R} \int_0^{\pi} d\theta  \, e^{-\min{(a,b)} R \sin{\theta} } \le \frac{2}{R} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta  \, e^{-2 \min{(a,b)} R \theta/\pi} \le \frac{\pi}{\min{(a,b)} R^2}$

Comment: Use $\sin{t} \ge \frac{2 t}{\pi}$ when $t \in [0.\pi/2]$.

Comment: I think there must be a $cos (\theta)$in the exponent of $e^{-\min{(a,b)} R \sin{\theta} } \le \frac{2}{R} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta  $?!!!

Comment: @MAh2014: Nope.  This is an estimate, and one of the exponents dominates the other one over the integration region.  The cosine piece then gets eliminated because we are taking magnitudes of the integrand (which is justified by Cauchy-Schwartz).

Comment: Sorry I meant this one:$e^{-2 \min{(a,b)} R \theta/\pi} $

Comment: @MAh2014: I have no idea what you are asking.  Look at the inequality I posted in my first comment.  Aside from that, I am not a tutoring service and have no time to hold your hand through this.  If this is a problem in a course in complex analysis, you should be able to follow what I have provided.  If you are having trouble, then consult a teacher or a tutor.

Comment: Sorry I thought you have transform  $\theta$ to $2 \theta $ to change the interval  to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ but I've got it now :).

Answer (score 2):

**Double integral**
$$
\begin{aligned}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos (a x)-\cos (b x)}{x^2} d x = & \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} \int_a^b \sin (x y) d y d x \\
= & \int_a^b \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (x y)}{x} d x d y \\
= & \int_a^b \frac{\pi}{2} d y\\=&\frac{\pi}{2}(b-a)
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

It can be seen as a limit case of [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html), but it also follows from:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2\,dx \stackrel{i.b.p.}{=}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2} $$
since:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x^2}\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\sin\frac{ax}{2}}{x}\right)^2\,dx. $$

Answer (score 0):

Using the trigonometric identity in my comment above... Let $y=1/x$. Then $-dx/x^2=dy$ and we have

$$-\frac{1}{2}I=\int_0^{\infty}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}(a+b)/y\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}(a-b)/y\right)dy.$$

Mathematica gives the primitve to be, which can probably be obtained using i.b.p.,
$$-\frac{a \text{Si}\left(\frac{a}{y}\right)}{2}-\frac{1}{2} y \cos \left(\frac{a}{y}\right)+\frac{b \text{Si}\left(\frac{b}{y}\right)}{2}+\frac{1}{2} y \cos \left(\frac{b}{y}\right),$$
where $\text{Si}$ is the sine integral, which evaluates over the limits to be
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\left|b\right|-\left|a\right|\right)$$
for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.
Not a proof, but an alternative outline to the residue calculus perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

By integration by part, we reduce the power 2. $$
\begin{aligned}
& \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (a x)-\cos (b x)}{x^{2}} d x \\
=&-\int_{0}^{\infty}[\cos (a x)-\cos (b x)] d\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \\
=&\left.-\left[\frac{\cos (a x)-\cos b x}{x}\right]_{0}^{\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{-a \sin (a x)+b \sin (b x)}{x}dx\right]\\=&-a \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (a x)}{x} d x+b\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (b x)}{x} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the formula, $$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (k x)}{x} d x=\frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{sgn}(k),
$$
We can conclude that
$$
 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (a x)-\cos (b x)}{x^{2}} d x =\frac{\pi}{2}(|b|-|a|)
$$