# Integral: $\int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin (2x)| - | \sin (3x) |}x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Can someone help me with this integral? I can't even think of where to begin.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin (2x)| - | \sin (3x) |}x dx$$

Thanks!

Comment: own effoerts????

Comment: Surely you must have tried something, SenhorJose'

Comment: This might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/449934/1242