# How do I evaluate integrals of the form $\int_{0}^\infty {{e^{-x}\over x}dx}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to evaluate integrals of the form $\int_{0}^\infty {{e^{-x}\over x}dx}$

I tried taylor expanding, but that didn't help. What is the way to evaluate these integrals.

Specifically I need to evaluate $\int_{0}^\infty {{e^{-x\over \sqrt{3}}-{e^{-x\over \sqrt{2}}}\over x}dx}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Frullani's Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html)
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x}dx=\ln\left(\frac ba\right)\quad,\quad a,b>0$$
**Another Way**

You can use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform). Let $\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=F(s)$, We have

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}F(s)ds=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t) \mathrm{dt}\mathrm{ds}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\mathrm{ds}\right)f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}\mathrm{dt}$$
As a result
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}F(s)ds=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}\mathrm{dt}$$

Now apply the result for $f(t)=e^{-at}$ , and $f(t)=e^{-bt}$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{s+a}-\frac{1}{s+b}\right)ds=\ln\left(\frac{s+a}{s+b}\right)\Big{|}_{0}^{\infty}=-\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$

Comment: Can you share a proof of this as well?

Comment: @PruthviBharadwaj http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/proof-of-frullanis-theorem

Answer (score 2):

The first integral you mentioned does not converge. To see this, observe
$$ \int_0^1 x^{-1} \mathrm dx = +\infty
$$
Therefore
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm e^{-x}}{x} \mathrm dx \geq \mathrm e^{-1} \int_0^1 x^{-1} \mathrm dx = +\infty
$$
so you should not be breaking down the second integral.

Comment: Question: Why do you write $\mathrm e$ when you could just write $e$? Also, +1.

Comment: @S.C.B. Maybe because $\mathrm e$ is not a variable?

Comment: Well, it's just that most people on this site seem to just write it as $e$.