# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {b \sin (ax) - a \sin (bx)}{x^2}dx$ for $a,b \gt 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

I want to calculate the integral which is dependent on the parameters $a$ and $b$ ($a,b \gt0)$.

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {b \sin (ax) - a \sin (bx)}{x^2}dx$

This integral is solved in my textbook but I don't understand how and why  like this:

$ab \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {b \sin (ax- a \sin (bx)}{abx^2}dx=ab \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{x} (\frac {\sin (ax)}{ax} - \frac { \sin (bx)}{bx})dx = ab \ln (\frac {b}{a})$

$f(x) = \frac {1}{x}$, ${}$ $\lim_{\to \infty} \frac {sinx}{x}=0$, ${}$ $\lim_{\to 0^+} \frac {sinx}{x}=1$

I just can't see it how they calculated it. Thanks.

Comment: check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/proof-of-frullanis-theorem

Comment: Well, I usually differentiate these types of integrals with the respect of the parameter, just I don't see it there. I have calculated many intgral like this, my problem is maybe more technical. It didn't help me to simplify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Frullani's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral), we see that
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x}\ dx = [f(\infty)-f(0)]\ln \frac{a}{b}.
\end{align}

Comment: Ok, I didn't know this formula exists, thank you.

Comment: Should be $x$ and not $x^2$ in the denominator, right?

Comment: @mickep Thanks for the correction.