# Improper integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{f(ax)-f(bx)} x \, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

$f(x)$ is continuous for $x \geq 0$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \ell.$

How do I show that for any $a, b > 0$, we have $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(ax)-f(bx)} x \, dx = (f(0) - \ell)\log\frac{b}{a}$$

I was thinking something along the lines of we can express it in the form $$\lim _{m \to 0}\int_m^1 \frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x} \, dx +  \lim _{n \to \infty}\int_1^n\frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x} \, dx$$ but then I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/proof-of-frullanis-theorem already answered here