# Calculate the integral by using Fubini's theorem

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

**Exercise**
Compute integral $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-{(3x)}^2}- e^{-{(6x)}^2}}{x} dx$$

**My attempt and questions:**

So we can write it as 
$$\frac{e^{-{(tx)}^2}}{x} |_6^3 \Rightarrow \int_0^{\infty}dx \int_6^3 -2txe^{-(tx)^2}dt$$

We can change order of intigration By Funini's theorem if function is positive which clearly is not as we have minus in front or if we show that $$\int\int_{[0,{\infty}]x[6,3] }2txe^{-(tx)^2} = \int_0^{\infty}dx \int_6^3 |-2txe^{-(tx)^2}| dt = \int_0^{\infty}dx \int_6^3 2txe^{-(tx)^2} dt < \infty$$

$$2 \int_0^{\infty} x dx \int_6^3 te^{-(tx)^2} dt  =^{per partes} ln{\frac{1}{2}} < \infty$$

**My question** Did i calculate corrrectly?

**Solving further** Hence by Fubini's theore, we can change order of intigration:

$$\int_6^3 -2t dt \int_0^{\infty}  xe^{-(tx)^2}dx$$

And here i am stuck because i get infinity by solving by the help of pwr partes.

**My question**Could somone please help to proceed?

Comment: $\log(6^2/3^2)=2\log(2)$

Comment: Actually, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/proof-of-frullanis-theorem) is a proof with Fubini's theorem in use

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-9x^2}-e^{-36x^2}}{x}\,dx&=2\int_0^\infty\int_3^6 ye^{-xy^2} \,dy\,dx\\\\
&=2\int_3^6\int_0^\infty ye^{-xy^2} \,dx\,dy\\\\
&=2 \int_3^6 \frac1y\,dy \\\\
&=2\log(2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi.  Would you please let me know how I can improve my answer?  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  If this was not useful, I am happy to delete it.  Looking forward to your reply.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit of course. ;-)