# Compute $\int_0^\infty \frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x}dx.$

Tags: integration

Let $f:[0,\infty [\to \mathbb R$ a continuous function such that $\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ converge. Prove that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x}dx$$
converge and compute this integral.

**Attempts**

For the convergence : Since for all $t>0$, $$\int_t^\infty \frac{f(ax)}{x}dx\quad \text{and}\quad \int_t^\infty \frac{f(bx)}{x}dx$$

converge, we have that $\int_0^\infty \frac{f(ax)}{x}dx$ and $\int_0^\infty \frac{f(bx)}{x}dx$ that converge, and thus $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x}dx.$$

But how I can compute this integral ?

Comment: Your argument for convergence is not correct. Example : $\int_t^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx$, $t>0$.

Comment: That's a Frullani's integral. You may read about them https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/proof-of-frullanis-theorem