# An Idea to solve a limit involve integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous function over $[0,1]$,and $0<a<b$ find the below limit $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}{\int_{at}^{bt}\frac{f(x)}{x}}=?$$
My work is below
$\int_{at}^{bt}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\int_{at}^{bt}f(x)d(\ln(x))$

Using the mean value theorem, and $f\in c^1[0,1]$ we have $$\exists c:a<c<b \ |f(ct)=\frac{\int_{at}^{bt}f(x)d(\ln(x))}{\ln(bt)-\ln(at)}$$ so $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}{\int_{at}^{bt}\frac{f(x)}{x}}=\lim_{t\to 0^+}{\int_{at}^{bt}f(x)d(\ln(x))}=\\
\lim_{t\to 0^+}f(ct)ln(\frac{bt}{at})=f(0)\ln(\frac ba)
$$
My questions:
1:Is my working true?
2:Is there another Idea or method to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think in several places you mean $f(x)$ not $(x)$...?

Comment: Hard to read the first displayed limit of an integral in your post. Now the integrand just looks like $\frac{(x)}{x}$ which simplified is just $1.$ Is there some function missing? Maybe $\ln(x)$ ?

Comment: I do apologize about missed $f(x)$, I fixed it.

Comment: @Isaac Browne: thanks for editing.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I don't immediately see the connection to Frullani's theorem. Could you elucidate the connection to this problem?

Comment: @IsaacBrowne:Let me see the post, and read it.please

Comment: @Khosrotash I believe this is the post CameronWilliams was referring to: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61828/429987. In any case, you should be able to see my post on this question here still

Comment: @CameronWilliams I see the connection now. This is an important step in the proof of Frullani's theorem, but I believe this question is different enough to be reopened.

Comment: @IsaacBrowne Ah yeah I figured since the proof was contained in there, it was better just to direct it that way.

Comment: Every time I see a limit question all of the answers always miss the easy $u$ substitution. Let $tu = x$

Comment: @CameronWilliams Fair point

Comment: can you not substitute $u=\frac xt$ then justify interchanging the limit and integral to get $$f(0)\int_a^b\frac 1u\,du$$

Answer (score 1):

A couple things. First the assumption only says $f$ is continuous, not that $f\in C^1[0,1]$, so mean value theorem doesn't work.

Second, I believe the bounds in the integrals should be $\ln(at)$ and $\ln(bt)$ when you've switched to $d(\ln(x))$. Though this could just be some convention I am unaware of.

A similar idea is to use inequalities to bound it i.e.
$$\int_{at}^{bt} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx \leq \sup_{at \leq x \leq bt} f(x) \int_{at}^{bt}\frac{1}{x}dx = \ln(b/a)\sup_{at\leq x\leq bt}f(x) $$
and
$$\int_{at}^{bt} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx \geq \inf_{at \leq x \leq bt} f(x) \int_{at}^{bt}\frac{1}{x}dx = \ln(b/a)\inf_{at\leq x\leq bt}f(x) $$
Since we are taking $t\to 0$ and $f$ is continuous, both the supremum and infimum will become $f(0)$ in the limit.