# Evaluation of $\int_0^\infty dx \left(\frac{e^{-iax} - e^{-ibx}}{x} \right)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have problem in order to compute the integral $$\int_0^\infty dx \left(\frac{e^{-iax} - e^{-ibx}}{x}\right) $$

The result should be
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty dx \left(\frac{e^{-iax} - e^{-ibx}}{x}\right) =
\begin{cases}
-\ln\left(\displaystyle{\frac{a}{b}}\right), \quad \quad \quad a>b
\\
-\ln\left(\displaystyle{\frac{a}{b}}\right) + i\pi, \quad a<b
\end{cases}
\end{align}

I don't know which contour taken in order to achieve this result.

Comment: Use a section of a torus in the third quadrant, I think.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/proof-of-frullanis-theorem