# Proving that $\displaystyle\log |x-y|=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 t}\left(e^{-\frac{1}{2 t}}-e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{2 t}}\right) d t$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Why is this identity true, I couldn't proceed and make any progress, can anyone help. Thank you.
$$\displaystyle\log |x-y|=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 t}\left(e^{-\frac{1}{2 t}}-e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{2 t}}\right) d t$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an instance of [Frullani integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral)
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{f(at)-f(bt)}{t}dt=[f(\infty)-f(0)]\log\frac ab
$$
with
$f(t)=e^{-\frac1{2t}}$, $a=1$, $b=\frac1{|x-y|^2}$.

The above formula assumes that $f(0)$ and $f(\infty)$ - considered as limits - exist. For future applications keep however in mind that this is not the necessary condition (this is not mentioned in the above wikipedia page). It is sufficient that the following limits exist:
$$
\tilde f(0)=\lim_{x\to0^+}x\int_x^1\frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt,\quad\text{and}\quad
\tilde f(\infty)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac1x\int_1^xf(t)dt.
$$
A proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/449934).

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Document123D You're welcome. You can accept an answer, which you consider most useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it by elementary means by first noticing that
$$
1/r = \int_0^\infty e^{-rt}\,\mathrm dt.
$$
Integrating with respect to $r$ gives
$$
\ln(r) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t} \left(e^{-t}-e^{-rt}\right)\mathrm dt.
$$
Now your formula follows by doing the change of variable $t\to 1/(2t)$, and then taking $r=|x-y|^2$ and using the fact that $\ln(|x-y|^2) = 2 \ln(|x-y|)$.

Comment: thank you so much,

Answer (score 0):

Letting $u=\frac 1 {2t}$ transforms the integral into
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2 t}}-e^{-\frac{k^2}{2 t}}}{t} d t= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-u}-e^{-k^2 u}}{u} d u
$$
Using a double integral, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_0^{\infty} \int_1^{k^2} e^{-u s} d s d u \\
& =\int_1^{k^2} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-u s} du d s \\
& =\int_1^{k^2}\left[\frac{e^{-u s}}{-s}\right]_0^{\infty} d s \\
& =\int_1^{k^2} \frac{1}{s} d s \\
& =\ln k^2 
\end{aligned}
$$
Replacing $k$ by $|x-y|$ yields $$\displaystyle\log |x-y|=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 t}\left(e^{-\frac{1}{2 t}}-e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{2 t}}\right) d t$$